# Alternative Way To Share Files On Local Host

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-share

I wanna create an application in Java that shares data with other computers on my local network so that I can access all the data from any computer on my network..

I know there is network sharing on windows but it's too slow to work with.. I want to copy big data in less time.. That means I need to increase the speed of transferring data..

I also want what will it be like if I used sockets ? I didn't use socket to transfer big data before so I don't know the speed of transfer.. Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion: you'll still be using the OS sockets through system calls (by the JVM) so you're gaining nothing.

A thumb rule I use is: the closer you are to the OS code - the better performance you're gonna get and you can't perform better than the OS because the OS is the bottleneck of your sockets/app anyway.

Comment: Aha.. Thanks for replying.. So I can not increase the speed using any software or even another OS ?

Comment: IMHO the host OS is your bottleneck anyway (The way its sockets are implemented)

Answer (score 0):

TCP sockets are realistically only limited by the speed of your network, custom data transfer over a socket should be able to out-perform windows file shares.

Any data transfer by sockets in java should be very close to the the speed of an FTP transfer over the same network.

As an experiment I would suggest setting up an FTP server on one of your machines and see how fast that works from the others. (Check out FileZilla if you're not familiar with FTP on Windows.)